# Vbscript to query computer name and then write to registry HKLM\software dword?

Tags: vbscript

Hi could any one point me in the right direction to create Vbscript to query computer name and then write the query result to registry HKLM\software\test dword or string

this is what i have got so far i just dont know how to link the query then add the query result to the registry -thanks in advance

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName"
strValueName = "ComputerName"
oReg.GetExpandedStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath, _
strValueName,strValue
```

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

From Help https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764

Computername

```
     Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
     WScript.Echo "Domain = " & WshNetwork.UserDomain
     WScript.Echo "Computer Name = " & WshNetwork.ComputerName
     WScript.Echo "User Name = " & WshNetwork.UserName
```

Write Registry

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\ACME\FortuneTeller\", 1, "REG_BINARY"
```